# Sending a URL to a Flask endpoint results in a 500 error

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask endpoint defined as below.

When I attempt to use any of the below I get an error 500 under the circumstances where I attempt to send the URL as the search parameter.

I've attempted to send the url in three different formats each of them failing in some way. And I can't figure out how to send this.

I've got this working on a separate project where I had just a string being sent and I can't figure out what is different here.

### A non url string

```
## Curl
`curl http://localhost:8080/search/'sdfsdf'` 
 
 ## Result on console
 {"message": "Internal Server Error"}

 ## Result on server
 Invalid URL 'sdfsdf': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://sdfsdf? 
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2020 16:54:39] "GET /search/sdfsdf HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

### A URL string

```
 ## Curl
 curl http://localhost:8080/search/'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election'

 ## Result on console
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <title>404 Not Found</title>
 <h1>Not Found</h1>
 <p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

 ## Result on server
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2020 16:58:34] "GET /search/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

### A URL String with converted slashes and semi colons

```
## Curl
curl http://localhost:8080/search/'https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F2016_United_States_presidential_election' 

 ## Result on console
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <title>404 Not Found</title>
 <h1>Not Found</h1>
 <p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

 ## Result on server
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2020 16:57:35] "GET /search/https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F2016_United_States_presidential_election HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

### API

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()


##############################
# LOADERS
##############################

class SearchForPage (Resource):
    # SEARCHES FOR A MATCHING WIKIPEDIA URL
    # IF EXISTS RETURN
    #   Headers Array
    #   References Array
    # IF NOT EXISTS
    #   URL Not Found Message

    def get(self, query_url):
        print(query_url)
        if(query_url):
            title = ScrapeTitle(query_url)
            return("You sent me to : " + title)

        else:
            return ("I didn't find anything at: " + query_url)


##############################
# ROUTES
##############################

# Route_1
## ACCEPTS A URL AS A VARIABLE
## GET  (RETURNS) AN ID IF EXISTS
##      (RETURNS) 'NO RECORDS' IF NOT EXISTS
api.add_resource(SearchForPage, '/search/<string:query_url>')
```

Comment: api.add_resource(SearchForPage.get, '/search/<string:query_url>')

Comment: That results in: `resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, *resource_class_args,
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'`

Comment: i dont know how you wrote resource_func but if you go by simple `@app.route('/search/<search_query>', methods=['Get'])` then it become easy to implement and test with the postman

Comment: I didn't write resource_func, that appears to be a system error. Separately, why use `@app.route` when `api.add_resource` has worked well? I'm only looking for whatever it is that's stripping the apostrophes from the url that's being passed to the api.